# How to let user, by text input, choose which function to use

Tags: php

How can I let a user (e.g. admin), by text input, choose which function to use?

I have really tried to think of a solution for this, and I really don't want to use eval, I can't even use it anyways because it is disabled (which is good), but I need the user to be able to specify what function the program needs to perform for a couple of times.

It is a general function that allows you to choose which function you want to perform, and then performs the function a lot of times.

Let me give an example that should work: (but I don't want to do this, because it uses eval, and eval is also disabled)

```php
function generate_random_integer($a, $b) {
    ...
}

function rinse_and_repeat($array, $count) {
    $function_name = $array[0];
    
    $params = $array[1];
    $param_string = implode(",", $params);
    
    $query= '$function_name($param_string);';

    $total = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $value = eval($query);
        if($verbose) { print($value); }
        $total += $value;
    }
    $ratio = $total/$count;
    
    return($total);
}

$input = array("generate_random_integer", array(1, 10));
$total = rinse_and_repeat($input, 100);
```

Don't stare blind on the "generate_random_integer", I know I can do that with other functions, but I want a general solution for letting the user choose which function to perform.

How do I make something similar to this, without using eval?
Can you only do this with eval or similar functions?

Comment: Maybe `call_user_func()` will help you? https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: I have looked into that, but I don't really seem to get it working, replacing the eval function with call_user_func() with all the correct parameters just makes my script time-out, even if I set it to the least amount of repetitions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OOPs, you can probably make use of strategy design pattern, which is a good practice. Using this pattern you can create object of a class based on user input

Create different class for each user input, so that you can create object of that particular class. All methods that depend on user input can go into that class.

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/php/example

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? Maybe a link to the corresponding PHP page? Your current answer is a bit too vague for me to be applicable or helpful.

Comment: Thank you, that made it more clear to me. Yes I suppose this is indeed an option, but for the small scale projects that I make, working with interfaces and all the OOP shizzle is more often a bit out of scope/overkill. I was more hoping for a quick fix three-liner or something like that ;-)